# Page with Mix of Dynamic and Static content

Tags: 7

I have to create a page that:

- has a mix of dynamic and static content
- can only be viewed by authenticated users

Currently, this is how I'm approaching it (but I know there is a much better way)

- created a page
- created Views blocks that are pulling in dynamic content and set permissions so that only authenticated users can view
- created static blocks and set permissions so only authenticated users can see

Is there a way to create one Views page that pulls in a mix of other Views blocks and static blocks? Is this at all possible? If not, is there a way to set the permissions for a basic page so that I would only have to set permissions once instead of doing it for each Views and static block? I know there is TAC module and Content Access but I had uploaded and it wasn't working well with the current site.

Thank you for any guidance you can provide!

Comment: did you try put all your blocks in a panel and give the panel permission you want

Comment: as Ahmed, i would suggest [panels](drupal.org/project/panels) and page manager : it looks a little complicated in the beginning ...  but lets you create exactly the type of stuff you are asking for - just convert yhose views into blocks and you can place them on the page easily.

Comment: Thank you both so much! I'm now using Panels and it's great for what I needed to do. I'm probably missing something but is there a way to easily add CSS to different columns through Panels (for example I have two columns and want to apply one class to the left side and one to the right). Currently I'm just seeing an option to add or remove CSS for the whole page. Thank you!